In counterpoint why can I not harmonize a 3rd to a 5th interval in the outer voices?
I am studying counterpoint and have a 3rd moving outward to a 5th. I now want to harmonize these two intervals (adding inner voices) and wherever I put them in the major scale it sounds poor and not convincing. It also doesn't relate to any functional progression. Try it: take any 3rd in the c major scale.. lets take D to F expanding outward to C and G. Yes I could write a C chord but going to a C chord from a Dmin chord sounds rather weak in functional harmony and is considered bad syntax.
Similarly on all other scale degrees I have similar problems, In my counterpoint excercise it would be perfectly ok to move to a perfect 5th by contrary motion yet I am unable to harmoniz this. Can anyone explain why or give me some ideas?
Addition: The very purpose of CP is to get a good outer voice structure, a 3rd to a 5th by contrary is good voice leading yet I can't get a good chord progression out of it yet

The figure you describe is fairly common in imitative counterpoint when the figure being imitated ascends and then descends in stepwise motion.  Bach's Amen and Dona nobis pacem from the B minor mass is an example, as is Josquin's (or De la Rue's) Absalon fili mi.

In a comment, I wrote

The figure you describe is fairly common in imitative counterpoint when the figure being imitated ascends and then descends in stepwise motion. Bach's "Amen" and "Dona nobis pacem" from the B minor mass is an example, as is Josquin's (or De la Rue's) Absalon fili mi.

Having looked more closely at these examples, and searching for others in music of the common practice period, I would say that you're more likely to find this in renaissance music than baroque or later.  It is pretty rare (in Bach at least) for this to happen between outer voices in 4-voice counterpoint without something else going on such as a suspension.  (I saw several examples in three-voice fugues in book one of the Well Tempered Clavier, the middle voice doubling one of the two outer voices on the first note and then moving in parallel with the other voice to make the second note a triad.)
In the Amen/Dona Nobis, the fifth becomes a sixth by oblique motion as the upper voice ascends by step and the bass remains (e.g. bass = D, C, C and soprano = F, G, A).  Stepwise contrary motion is much more likely to be 6th-to-octave or 4th-to-6th, with the latter case being the common 4/2 to 6 progression, as in V(4/2) to I6.
One problem with the question as stated is that you say "any third moving to any fifth" but then have the example of ^2 and ^4 moving to ^1 and ^5, which makes one think of cadences, but as you and Michael Curtis have both noted, this isn't a strong cadential formula.  I just looked through the chorales of the St. Matthew Passion, and the first good example I found was several chorales in, movement 46, where the second phrase begins C♯ D E F♯ in the soprano, with F♯ B A D in the bass.  The second chord has a third (tenth) that expands outward on the third.  The alto has F♯ F♯ A A and the tenor has A♯ B C♯ D (the piece is in B minor).  The chords are therefore V, i (= vi/III), V/III, III, and the voice leading is as Michael Curtis gives in his answer.
But for the most part, parallel stepwise motion is harmonized with thirds and sixths, and here if the first chord is a 6 chord with the third in the soprano then the sixth is a fifth below the soprano and you have a parallel fifth when both ascend.  If the inner voice descends instead, it can drop a third to double the soprano in the lower octave, giving a doubled fifth.  If the second chord is a 6/5 chord the sixth can descend stepwise in parallel with the bass, but then it is a seventh below the soprano without proper preparation.  Scanning the WTC, I saw a few instances of these sorts of things being avoided with suspensions or leaps, but in strict note-for-note counterpoint, of course, that isn't possible.
All of this leads to the suggestion that you may want to reconsider your soprano and bass parts.  Do you really need the third moving to a fifth, or would another solution be more idiomatic?

phoog, you're right, that progression you mentioned is a very idiomatic progression and the rising line works well with the bass moving down a step and then a descending fifth. So I guess that solves it. However, on other scale degrees this might not work as well as it does with this progression (unless applied chords are used) and it really only works to my ears if the middle chord is a kind of passing chord. DEfinitely the best harmonization of that outer voice CP for now

Also see Mozarts Lacrymosa.. it has the same progression used several time and used with applied dominants. It was a coincidence that I was just studying that piece and saw the same progression :)


The very purpose of CP is to get a good outer voice structure, a 3rd to a 5th by contrary is good voice leading yet I can't get a good chord progression out of it yet

Well, sort of. If we think of outer voices as bass and soprano, and those two voices are more important than subordinate inner voices, that really is more of the basic homophonic texture, chord based music. The purpose of counterpoint is more like harmonizing melodic lines where no melodic line is subordinate to another. Horizontally, counterpoint seeks good, equally important melodic lines in each part. Vertically, counterpoint seeks variety of harmonic intervals.
Anyway, the given task is a third moving by contrary motion to a perfect fifth, in the outer voices, I'll assume C major, D F moving to C G, and completing that as four part harmony.
D F gives us a third, which can work as an incomplete triad, but the empty C G with no third should be filled in first, so we add to it E, and it has to be a middle voice, that gives us D F to C E G.
Let's continue with D F should be a ii, Dm chord, as suggested in the OP's question. That means the progression is ii I, root progression by descending step, a weak progression. It also means all voices move. There is a general voice leading rule of thumb, that when all voices move, it should be done as all upper voices move in contrary motion to the bass, and the upper voices move the smallest distance to their next chord tones. The bass is given as a requirement of the question, descending step D C, therefore all the upper voices should move ascending, and of those three upper voices, the soprano needs to be F G. So adding the alto and tenor below that soprano, in close voicing, is A D F to C E G. Both chords are in root position, and the chord roots are the doubled tones. I think this should be the standard way to complete the harmony following basic voice leading rules.
The harmony ii I is considered "weak", but that isn't necessarily a problem, depending on how it occurs. If the progression is surrounded by other strong progressions, if the phrase ends with a good cadence, it should probably be ok.
Another possibility that should work, but uses different doublings and incomplete triads would be D D F F to C E E G. That can be viewed as a composite of two similar motions D F descending to C E and D F ascending to E G. If it were in three parts only, it's bass descending D C with upper voices in contrary motion D F ascending to E G, which sort of preserves the voice leading rule of thumb to move the upper voices in contrary motion against the bass. In four parts, doubling the thirds of the chords, is not ideal, but it could be justified by melodic choices.

Thanks Michael, I was looking at the intervals as outer voices. I thought that would be obviouse but I was wrong. Those are the most important voices so could you edit your answer a bit please? sorry about this. Yes a plain 2 voice 5th is empty sounding but if you harmonize these bass notes with those soprano notes you would naturally add an alto and tenor voice to fill the chords up

@armani, OK, those are the outer voices. Do you want three voices total in the end?

would 4 be possible? I am used to 4 part writing

OK, but I'm getting a little confused. Do you specifically want D F to be a Dm chord? If not, then the obvious functional choice is make D F dominant of some kind where you really want the F to descend to E. Anyway, Dm to C, with your outer voices, I think the thing to do is double the D and have it expand contrary to C E. So, D D F to C E G. Bass is D C upper voices is ascending motion in thirds D F to E G. I can update my answer, if that's what you're after.

A fourth voice would probably be A ascends to C, all voices ascend against bass descending D C, or F doubled and splits to E G and so E is doubled in the C chord.

Michael, any 3rd going to any P5 in the outer voices

One problem with the pattern as given, minor third to perfect fifth, is that both tones move by whole-step. From Guido of Arezzo to Guido Adler, movement by a half-step has been preferred, either two half-steps or whole-step plus half-step. The pattern D-F#->C-G sounds better, but the fifth sounds hollow. (The perfect is the enemy of the good?) A short scan of several two-part counterpoint exercises and associated comments suggests that only imperfect consonance sounds good except for the first and last notes; these are either unisons or octaves, and fifths are avoided. I also tried Db-F->C-G and Db-F#->C-G; both seem to "need" an E in the final chord.
The point of species counterpoint is to learn the sounds and handling of simple intervals. Maybe "avoid perfect fifths" should be in the penumbra of "rules."

Hello, I did mention harmonizing the intervals. I will update the question slightly.

I found this while looking at other stuff: https://www.academia.edu/31868322/Chapter_3_Pietro_Pontios_Approach_to_Interval_Succession_Theory.  It seems that Pontios does have some extensive explanation of third to fifth succession.
